# Bootstrap Modal Issues Re-Using

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to re-use a modal for up to six different possible buttons.

This is the modal code I use:

```
div id="confirmation-modal" class="selfserve-confirmation-modal" tabindex="-1" modal="" role="dialog">
<a data-dismiss="modal" class="close-details"><span>close</span></a>

<div class="confirmation-details">
  <div class="confirmation-details-section">
   <p id="confirmation-modal-details-primary"></p>
   <p id="confirmation-modal-details-secondary"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
   <div class="no-show-check">
    <input id="confirmation-modal-no-more" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="confirmation-modal-no-more"></label>
    <span>Please do not show me this message again this session.</span>
   </div>
   <div>
    <button id="confirmation-modal-confirm" type="button" class="primary-button confirm">Ok</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have a showConfirmationModal function:

```
function showConfirmationModal(attribute, buttonId, secondaryMessage) {
   $("#confirmation-modal").attr("modal", attribute);
   $("#confirmation-modal-details-secondary").html(secondaryMessage);
   $(".confirm").attr('id', buttonId);
   $("#confirmation-modal").modal({
      show: true,
      backdrop: false,
      keyboard: true
   });
}
```

And my show backdrop and close functions:

```
  $(".selfserve-confirmation-modal").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $(this).before('<div class="modal-backdrop in"></div>');
      $(this).css("z-index", parseInt($('modal-backdrop').css('z-index')) + 1);
   });


   $('.close-details').on('click', function () {
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        $('#confirmation-modal').hide();
        $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
   });
```

Finally, here are two "calls" to the modal.

```
    $("#optinDomesticDataCap").click(function() {
        showConfirmationModal("MODAL", "optinDomestic", optinDomesticDataCapConfirmation);

        $("#optinDomestic").click(function() {
            doDataCapUpdate("${optinDomesticDataCap}", 
$("#domesticMessageContainer"));
    });
    });
```

and

```
    $("#increaseInternationalDataCap").click(function() {
        showConfirmationModal("MODAL", "increaseInternational", increaseInternationalDataCapConfirmation);

        $("#increaseInternational").click(function() {
            doDataCapUpdate("${increaseInternationalDataCap}", $("#internationalMessageContainer"));
        });
    });
```

I want to dynamically change the id of the div containing the OK button when the modal is brought up, so then when that OK button is clicked, the doDataCapUpdate function is run with the specific information (which pre-existed before the modals are introduced, and works fine).

I have tried to remove() the modal, but of course that removes it, so it can't be run again on that page.

I have tried hide(), but if I click one button, then close it, and click a different button, and click OK the function will run for both buttons, as if they were clicked.

Also, when I do click and run the function the first time, the modal cannot be brought up again by clicking other buttons.

I've wracked my brain for a couple of days on this, and I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what the right steps are to make this work.

Comment: This does not seem to be a bootstrap modal, or is a very alternative approach. Can you set up a fiddle that demonstrates how the code is working?

Comment: I created this fiddle, but it doesn't run, and displays the modal content in the html page...  not sure if there's a better way to do it.  https://jsfiddle.net/pvp087jw/2/